# MGF exists and yet derivative does not

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, moment-generating-functions, absolute-convergence

Consider the Moment Generating Function of the [Uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) $U(a,b)$ given by
$$M(t)=\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)} \mbox{if }t\ne 0; M(0)=1.$$

Now, it is well known that if MGF is finite in an interval around $0$, then derivatives of all orders exists (see for instance, Billingsley's book Probability and Measure pg 278). But here $M'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{M(t)-1}{t}$ does not seem to exist.

Why is that?

Comment: How is that the limit? I am applying L Hopitals rule but not getting it.

Comment: $$
M'(t)=\frac{be^{tb}-ae^{ta}}{t(b-a)}-\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t^2(b-a)}.
$$
Applying L'Hôpital's rule,
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}M'(t)=\frac{b^2e^{0\cdot b}-a^2e^{0\cdot a}}{b-a}-\frac{b^2e^{0\cdot b}-a^2e^{0\cdot a}}{2(b-a)}=\frac{a+b}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks....i had made a careless mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{M(t)-1}{t}=\frac{1}{b-a}\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}-t(b-a)}{t^2}$$
L'Hospital rule gives
$$\frac{M(t)-1}{t}\sim\frac{1}{b-a}\frac{be^{tb}-ae^{at}-(b-a)}{2t}\sim\frac{1}{b-a}\frac{b^2e^{bt}-a^2e^{at}}{2}\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow0}\frac{b+a}{2}$$